# find all the string values and the corresponding keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find all the string values from the array of objects and then format the keys.

```
//it works for a single object and string
// need help to implement an array of Object and string
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find((key) => object[key] === value);
}

const data = [
  {
    AddressFlag: true,
    BaseMasterTable: "DIMCUSTOMER",
     ContextName: "Kunden",
    DefaultOutputFormats: null,
    HouseHoldColumn: null,
    I18N: [],
    ID: 5,
    PrimaryKey: "CustomerKey",
    
  }
];

const mapper = data.map((item) => {
  const values = Object.values(item).filter((item) => typeof item === "string");
  console.log(values);
// problem here;
//it's now taking a single object and a single string
// how can I take an array of objects and strings as parameters here
  console.log(getKeyByValue(data[0], values[1]));
});
```

And finally output in this format

```
[
{fieldname: 'ContextName'},
{fieldName: 'PrimaryKey'},
{fieldName: 'BaseMasterTable'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object of array is iterated by `.flatMap()`. On each iteration the current object is converted into an array of pairs by `Object.entries()`

```js
data.flatMap(obj => Object.entries(obj)
// [["AddressFlag", true], ["BaseMasterTable", "DIMCUSTOMER"], [...], ...]
```

Next, `.flatMap()` is used again, but this time as a filter. Since `.flatMap()` flattens it's returns by a level we can apply a ternary or `if`/`else if`/`else` statement with a empty array (`[]`) as the `else` or last part of a ternary. Doing so will cleanly return nothing (instead of the usual empty (`""`)). This technique is especially useful because you can return anything -- in the example, the condition is checking each pair second element (`pair[1]` which is originally the value) and if it's the given type (in the example is `"string"`) the first element of the pair is returned as the value of an object (`pair[0]` which is originally the key). If it isn't the given type an empty array is returned.

```js
data.flatMap(obj => Object.entries(obj).flatMap(pair =>  
typeof pair[1] === "string" ? {"fieldName": pair[0]} : []))
// is "DIMCUSTOMER" a string ? return {"fieldName": "BaseMasterTable"} OR []
```

**Details are commented in example**

```js
const data = [{
  AddressFlag: true,
  BaseMasterTable: "DIMCUSTOMER",
  ContextName: "Kunden",
  DefaultOutputFormats: null,
  HouseHoldColumn: null,
  I18N: [],
  ID: 5,
  PrimaryKey: "CustomerKey"
}];

/**
 * Return an array of objects of which each object has a commonly shared key
 * and a value derived from the key of an object of a given array. The object
 * itself is determined by the given type of it's value.
 * @param {array<object>} array - An array of objects
 * @param {string} type - The type a value of an object property to accept
 * @param {string} [newKey = "fieldName"] - The name of the commonly shared
 *        key of each object in the returned array. If undefined it defaults
 *        to "fieldName".
 * @returns {array<object>} - An array of objects (see description above)
 */ 
function keysByType(array, type, newKey = "fieldName") {
  return array.flatMap(obj =>
    Object.entries(obj).flatMap(pair =>
      typeof pair[1] === type ? {
        [newKey]: pair[0]
      } : []));
}

console.log(keysByType(data, "string"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this approach with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) together. And [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to group all string data into a single array.

```js
const data = [{
  AddressFlag: true,
  BaseMasterTable: "DIMCUSTOMER",
  ContextName: "Kunden",
  DefaultOutputFormats: null,
  HouseHoldColumn: null,
  I18N: [],
  ID: 5,
  PrimaryKey: "CustomerKey",
}];

const mapper = data.flatMap((item) => {
  const result = Object.entries(item).filter(([key, value]) => typeof value === "string").map(([key, value]) => ({
    fieldname: key
  }));
  return result
});

console.log(mapper)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for this. Pretty simple:

```js
const data = [
  {
    AddressFlag: true,
    BaseMasterTable: "DIMCUSTOMER",
     ContextName: "Kunden",
    DefaultOutputFormats: null,
    HouseHoldColumn: null,
    I18N: [],
    ID: 5,
    PrimaryKey: "CustomerKey",
  },
  {
    AddressFlag: true,
    BaseMasterTable: "DIMCUSTOMER",
     ContextName: "Kunden",
    DefaultOutputFormats: null,
    HouseHoldColumn: null,
    I18N: [],
    ID: 5,
    PrimaryKey: "CustomerKey",
  }
];

const result = data.flatMap(element => {
  return Object.entries(element)
    .filter(([,value]) => typeof value === "string")
    .map(([key]) => ({fieldName: key}));
});

console.log(result)
```

This will duplicate keys, you can then filter if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is almost the same approach as provided answers. Only difference is it is one loop less. I'm using `flatMap` here instead of `filter` & `map`. Something like this:-

```js
const data = [{AddressFlag: true,BaseMasterTable: "DIMCUSTOMER",ContextName: "Kunden", DefaultOutputFormats: null, HouseHoldColumn: null, I18N: [],     ID: 5, PrimaryKey: "CustomerKey", } ];

const result = data.flatMap(e=>Object.entries(e).flatMap(([fieldName,v])=>typeof v==='string' ? ({fieldName}) : []));

console.log(result);
```